# How do SDDL protection descriptors work with CNG DPAPI

Tags: windows, windows-dpapi

[`NCryptCreateProtectionDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706800(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts various [Protection Descriptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769091(v=vs.85).aspx), and I can understand the examples shown like:

```
SID=S-1-5-21-4392301
```

But the examples also show SDDL based descriptors, like:

```
SDDL=O:S-1-5-5-0-290724G:SYD:(A;;CCDC;;;S-1-5-5-0-290724)(A;;DC;;;WD)
```

I'm not sure I follow how a SDDL based protection descriptor is supposed to work. Is the secret protected so that the SDDL *owner* can decrypt it? What does the various access rights in the SDDL come into play? Does an Deny ACE deny encryption, or what? Does a G allow encryption, how does that work with a group?

I cannot find any documentation on this topic, and mapping an SDDL to key exchange feels much like the square peg and round hole.